# how to put object in s3 from appsync

Tags: amazon-s3, velocity, aws-appsync

there is a way to connect appsync directly with s3, to store a base64?
i'm aware of this api [s3 PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) but i dont understand how to achieve it by using appsync vtl

given the following chunk of my schema...

```
Mutation uploadFile(base64: String): Response
```

...and assuming i have an http datasource for connecting to my bucket through s3 api... how can i put all pieces together?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working in following way:

Schema:

```
type Mutation {
  putFile(Key: ID!, base64: String!): File!
}
```

DataSource:

```
Type: HTTP
Endpoint: https://{bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Request mapping template:

```
#set( $content = $util.base64Decode($ctx.args.base64) )
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "method": "PUT",
  "params":{
    "headers":{
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
    "body":$content
  },
  "resourcePath": "/$ctx.args.Key"
}
```

Response mapping template (simplified):

```
#set( $body = $util.parseJson($util.xml.toJsonString($ctx.result.body)))
#if ( $ctx.result.statsCode != 200 )
  $util.error($body.Error.Message)
#end
$util.toJson({"Key":$ctx.args.Key})
```

Be aware that:

1. the request size limit of appsync is 1MB
2. You should probably handle content-type as input argument
3. You also need to grant access to S3 to created datasource